Lack of notification from loyalty object update
Updating a loyalty object
https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/loyaltyobject/update
Following the request body
https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/loyaltyobject#LoyaltyObject
Setting the [notifyPreference][1] field to NOTIFY_ON_UPDATE
But not seeing any updates on my device even though I've updated the supported fields.
In settings I have:

Notifications enabled for:

Google Play Services
Google Wallet

All Google Wallet Notifications enabled





What's more confusing is in the docs the payload for notifyPreferences specifies this enum
https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/NotificationSettingsForUpdates
But the docs read
Setting the notifyPreference to notifyOnUpdate will trigger a notification, provided the updated field is currently supported.

[1]: https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/loyaltyobject#LoyaltyObject:~:text=chosen%20by%20you.-,notifyPreference,-enum%20(NotificationSettingsForUpdates
